# Preserving Table Data Type Column from Power Query in Power BI Data Model

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

While performing data transformation in Power BI, I wanted to generate multiple columns for tables. However, when I try to export them to the Power BI canvas, the columns simply disappear. My objective here is to ensure that the columns remain as they are once I have applied the data transformation.

In the power query editor:

[image]

In power bi canvas:

[image]

I was expecting that the table column was exported to be edited on power Bi canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI data model does not have a ***table*** data type for it's data model and so these are discarded when you click close & apply. These columns can be expanded in Power Query by clicking the little arrows on the column header. Tables and Lists in Power Query are meant to be intermediate steps when you do you data transformations and your final step should be a standard table with columns containing numbers, letters, dates, times etc. Data types between Power Query and Power BI do not always match one-to-one though.

[image]